# How can I control the default date for date columns in the UltraWebGrid control?

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I'm using the **Infragistics UltraWebGrid** control and have the following layout:

```
<igtbl:UltraWebGrid ID="uwgPrescribedTrainingPlan" runat="server" Browser="Auto">
   <Bands>
      <igtbl:UltraGridBand DataKeyField="TRAININGPLANID">
         <Columns>
            ...
            <igtbl:UltraGridColumn HeaderText="Training Start Date" Key="STARTDATE" BaseColumnName="STARTDATE"
               DataType="System.DateTime" Format="MM-dd-yy" EditorControlID="wdcDateChooser" />
            <igtbl:UltraGridColumn HeaderText="Training End Date" Key="ENDDATE" BaseColumnName="ENDDATE"
               DataType="System.DateTime" Format="MM-dd-yy" EditorControlID="wdcDateChooser" />
            ...
         </Columns>
      </igtbl:UltraGridBand>
   </Bands>
</igtbl:UltraWebGrid>
```

The two important columns are `STARTDATE` and `ENDDATE`.  Both allow users to edit the cell using a calendar control.

Right now, if you change the value of an `ENDDATE` cell, the picker will default to the current date.  What I want is to default to the value of the `STARTDATE` column (if there is one).

I've looked around the docs and didn't find much, and the client side scripting API seems to be completely undocumented.  Does anyone know if this is possible to do?

**UPDATE**:

I can attach a handler to the `AfterDropDown` event of `wdcDateChooser`, however in that handler I don't see any way to get the row I clicked on in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have a solution.  I've attached the following Javascript to the `AfterDropDown` event of the `WebDateChooser` control like so:

`<ClientSideEvents AfterDropDown="InitEndDateDefault"></ClientSideEvents>`

The Javascript function is as follows:

```
function InitEndDateDefault(oDateChooser, dropDownPanel, oEvent)
{
   var cell = oDateChooser.webGrid.grid.getActiveCell();

   if (cell.Column.Key == "ENDDATE" && !oDateChooser.getValue())
   {
      var startDate = cell.getPrevCell().getValue();
      oDateChooser.Calendar.setSelectedDate(startDate);
   }
}
```